# Printing reports with Qt

Tags: qt, report, qtwebkit, qtwebengine

In my Qt applications I widely use reports printing. All of them were written with Qt < 5. Now I want to rewrite it with Qt5 but suddenly I come across the unexpected difficulty. I use HTML templates with placeholders and `QWebView` to print the document. But in Qt5 `QWebView` has buggy printing (see [QTBUG-35222](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-35222), [QTBUG-43145](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43145), [QTBUG-36308](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36308) etc.) So `QWebView` is out. Next candidate is `QWebEngine` but it does not work with Windows. (Or works partially with x86-64 and VS2013 but I need it to work with MInGW). So using `QWebEngine` is currently impossible. 
`QTextEdit` supports only limited subset of HTML and it does not support external css etc.

So now I look for some way to load and print HTML documents in Qt. Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure but what about using `QTextDocument`?

Comment: It not useful as I said it supports only limited subset of HTML and CSS. It's impossible to connect external CSS etc.

Comment: This works Ok in Qt 5.3.1. All of the bug reports that you refer to are essentially reporting the same issue, two of them are or should be duplicates of the other. For now, the solution is to stick to 5.3.1, and perhaps backport whatever other goodies you need from 5.4 (like for example the fix to [QTBUG-44349](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44349)). The only recourse you have is to fix Qt yourself, and submit the patches - iff you don't wish to wait for an official fix.

Comment: Thanks @KubaOber, that just made my day. It really works with 5.3.1. I'll try later to build 5.4 with the fix from bug report.